# How to scrape website with multiple pages using scrapy

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape [this website](https://abcd-terroir.smartrezo.com/n31-france/annuaireABCD.html?page=1&spe=1&anIDS=31&search=f&pcatid=0&pcat=Secteur%20d%27activit%C3%A9%20%3F#) (that has multiple pages), using scrapy. the problem is that I can't find the next page URL.
Do you have an idea on how to scrape a website with multiple pages (with scrapy) or how to solve the error I'm getting with my code?

I tried the code below but it's not working:

```py
class AbcdspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    Class docstring
    """
    name = 'abcdspider'
    allowed_domains = ['abcd-terroir.smartrezo.com']

    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    url = "https://abcd-terroir.smartrezo.com/n31-france/annuaireABCD.html?page=1&spe=1&anIDS=31&search="
    start_urls = [url + letter for letter in alphabet]

    main_url = "https://abcd-terroir.smartrezo.com/n31-france/"


    crawl_datetime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.crawler.stats.set_value("start_time", self.start_time)
        try:
            page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pageStuff"]/span/text()').get()
            page_max = get_num_page(page)

            for index in range(page_max):
                producer_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="clearfix encart_ann"]/@onclick').getall()
                for producer in producer_list:
                    link_producer = self.main_url + producer
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=link_producer, callback=self.parse_details)

                next_page_url = "/annuaireABCD.html?page={}&spe=1&anIDS=31&search=".format(index)

                if next_page_url is not None:
                    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(self.main_url + next_page_url))

        except Exception as e:
            self.crawler.stats.set_value("error", e.args)
```

I am getting this error:

```
'error': ('range() integer end argument expected, got unicode.',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pageStuff"]/span/text()').get()
page_max = get_num_page(page)
```

The range function expected an integer value (1,2,3,4, etc) not an unicode string ('Page 1 / 403'
)

My proposal for the range error is

```
page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pageStuff"]/span/text()').get().split('/ ')[1]

for index in range(int(page)):
    #your actions
```