# How to Scrape Multiple Pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This code returns null values ​​after clicking the 'Load more' button. Even adding a waiting time to load the page, it gives error.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from projeto_estadao.items import ProjetoEstadaoItem
from time import sleep  

class SiteEstadaoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "site_estadao"
    allowed_domains = ["busca.estadao.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["https://busca.estadao.com.br/?tipo_conteudo=Not%C3%ADcias&quando=01%2F01%2F2018-31%2F12%2F2022&q=%22Seguran%C3%A7a%20da%20informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22"]

    def parse(self, response):
        div_noticias = response.css('div.box')

        for div in div_noticias:
            sleep(5)
            link = div.css("section.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.col-margin > a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            title = div.css("section.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.col-margin > a > h3::text").extract_first()
            data = div.css("span.data-posts::text").extract_first()
            newspaper_section = div.css("div.label > h4::text").extract_first()

            notice = ProjetoEstadaoItem(link=link, title=title, data=data, newspaper_section=newspaper_section)
            yield notice

            
            next_page_button = response.css('a.go more-list-news btn-mais fn brd-e')
            if next_page_button:
                yield SeleniumRequest(
                    url=response.urljoin(next_page_button.attrib['href']),
                    callback=self.parse
                )
                
                if self.first_page_clicked:
                    sleep(10)  
                self.first_page_clicked = True  
    def start_requests(self):
        
        self.first_page_clicked = False
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

I need to loop through and scrape all the content on the page, but in this structure it just returns:

```
    {
        "link": "https://politica.estadao.com.br/blogs/fausto-macedo/376025-2/",
        "title": "Somos livres mesmo, de verdade?",
        "data": "24 de novembro de 2022 | 15h05",
        "newspaper_section": "Pol\u00edtica"
    },
    {
        "link": null,
        "title": null,
        "data": null,
        "newspaper_section": null
    },
```

Comment: Check out these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905178/how-to-scrape-website-with-multiple-pages-using-scrapy) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23898034/5181837) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729038/scrapy-load-more-result-pages)